# User controls to use same TCP connection as Main Form

Tags: c#, tcp, client, controls

I have a form that acts as a client GUI for a TCP client/server project. I have multiple User Controls that act as "pages" that the user can navigate using buttons on the main GUI form.

My issue is; each one of these user controls (as well as the main form) needs to be able to communicate with the server (ie. send messages to it).

Currently to accomplish this I'm opening a new connection every time a new user control is added, by placing the following code in my main form, as well as all of the user control "pages":

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;
    private TcpClient myClient = new TcpClient();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);
        myClient.Connect(serverEndPoint);
    }
}

private void SendMessage(string msg)
{
        NetworkStream clientStream = myClient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(msg);
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to have this code on my main form only, and have each user control that's added to the main form use the connection that's already open to communicate. I'm just not sure how I would accomplish this.

Comment: When you create the sub form classes, pass the open connection object to their constructor. Or, if you want to avoid parameterized form ctors, assign it to a public property of the form before displaying it. Edit: s/form/panel.

Comment: Any chance you could show me a little example of how to do that, or point me towards one? This is my first time using C#, and a lot of this stuff is very new to me. (Hence the probably considered "messy" way I'm doing things right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the connection in a static class and create static interface for connecting to the server and sending messages. You will only have to open the connection once, in you main form.

```
static public class ServerCommunicator
{
    static private IPEndPoint serverEndPoint;
    static private TcpClient myClient = new TcpClient();

    static public void Connect()
    {
        serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);
        myClient.Connect(serverEndPoint);
    }
    static public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        NetworkStream clientStream = myClient.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(msg);
        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

And you main form class becomes:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServerCommunicator.Connect();

        // Sending a message:
        ServerCommunicator.SendMessage("Hello server!");
    }
}
```

ServerCommunicator.Connect() only needs to be called once, in the main form. The other controls can simply call SendMessage.

Comment: I'll still have to add `ServerCommunicator.Connect();` to my user controls for them to be able to send messages though, correct?

Comment: I edited the answer. No you do not. The static resource only need to be connected once.

Comment: Okay, that sounds perfect, thanks. One issue I'm having now is I'm getting a `method must have a return type` error on `static public Connect()` and on `static public SendMessage(string msg)`

Comment: should they be `static public void` rather than just `static public`?

Comment: Yap, sorry. I wrote it on my phone.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought I had everything set up right, until I tried debugging. Where in my project should I have the `ServerCommunicator` class? or should I create a new, separate class for it? EDIT: Nevermind, created a separate class, everything works great! Thanks so much! This cleaned up my code greatly :)